# Getting the class name of the super class?

Tags: java, reflection

I am writing some code to check the structure of other people's code.

Lets say ClassB extends ClassA

I know I can do

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("classB");
clazz.getSuperclass();
clazz.getName(); //ClassA
```

but I dont want to do it this way because it requires my jvm return the actual class of ClassA (which is not in the classpath)

currently I am using

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("classB", false, classLoader);
```

to not initialize the class, so that I dont have to put so many irrelevant jars into my classpath.

Is there a way I can get the Super's classname from ClassB without requiring me to include ClassA's jar in the classpath?

Comment: Why not `Class.forName("classB", false, classLoader).getSuperclass()`?

Comment: If `ClassA` isn't on the classpath, you won't be able to load `ClassB extends ClassA`.

Comment: If `ClassA` is not in the classpath, then you need to read the `ClassB.class` file directly, so go **find a bytecode library** and read the file, to learn what superclass the file specifies. I mean, you could also try reading the file yourself, but why do that when there are free libraries available that knows how to read the file?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- you can still do
Class clazz = Class.forName("classB", false, classLoader); because you dont initialize the class, an example would be like looking at the .java file.

Answer (score 2):

There’s a fundamental misconception within

> currently I am using
>
> ```
> Class clazz = Class.forName("classB", false, classLoader);
> ```
>
> to not initialize the class, so that I dont have to put so many irrelevant jars into my classpath.

The `initialize` parameter specifies whether the static initializer should run, i.e. `static {}` blocks and non-constant initializer expressions of `static` fields. It does not prevent the loading of the superclass. That’s simply impossible.

It’s also strange to consider the superclass or its containing jar file “irrelevant”. The superclass is rather a *crucial* aspect of a class.

The JVM specification says:

> #### [5.3.5. Deriving a Class from a `class` File Representation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.5)
>
> The following steps are used to derive a `Class` object for the nonarray class or interface `C` denoted by `N` using loader `L` from a purported representation in `class` file format.
>
> …
>
> 3. If `C` has a direct superclass, the symbolic reference from `C` to its direct superclass is resolved using the algorithm of [§5.4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.1). Note that if `C` is an interface it must have `Object` as its direct superclass, which must already have been loaded. Only `Object` has no direct superclass.
>
>    Any exceptions that can be thrown due to class or interface resolution can be thrown as a result of this phase of loading. In addition, this phase of loading must detect the following errors:
>
>    - If any of the superclasses of `C` is `C` itself, loading throws a `ClassCircularityError`.
>    - Otherwise, if the class or interface named as the direct superclass of `C` is in fact an interface or a `final` class, loading throws an `IncompatibleClassChangeError`.
>    - Otherwise, if `C` is a class and some instance method declared in `C` can override ([§5.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.5)) a `final` instance method declared in a superclass of `C`, loading throws an `IncompatibleClassChangeError`.

It’s impossible to perform these mandatory checks without loading the superclass.

In principle, it’s possible to read a class’ superclass declaration without loading the class itself, which also prevents all kind of linkage problems, by reading and parsing the class file. It only needs a tiny change to make the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52332101/2711488) read the superclass name instead of the class name.

It still doesn’t change the fact that you can’t use a class without its superclass, so its usefulness is limited.

```java
static String getSuperClassNameOf(ClassLoader loader, String className)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    String resName = className.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
    InputStream is;
    getStream: {
        for(; loader != null; loader = loader.getParent()) {
            is = loader.getResourceAsStream(resName);
            if(is != null) break getStream;
        }
        is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(resName);
    }
    if(is == null) throw new ClassNotFoundException(className);
    className = getSuperClassName(ByteBuffer.wrap(is.readAllBytes()));
    return className.replace('/', '.');
}

static String getSuperClassName(ByteBuffer buf) {
    if(buf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt()!=0xCAFEBABE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a valid class file");
    }
    int minor=buf.getChar(), ver=buf.getChar(), poolSize=buf.getChar();
    int[] pool = new int[poolSize];
    //System.out.println("version "+ver+'.'+minor);
    for(int ix=1; ix<poolSize; ix++) {
        String s; int index1=-1, index2=-1;
        byte tag = buf.get();
        switch(tag) {
            default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "unknown pool item type "+buf.get(buf.position()-1));
            case CONSTANT_Utf8:
                buf.position((pool[ix]=buf.position())+buf.getChar()+2); continue;
            case CONSTANT_Module: case CONSTANT_Package: case CONSTANT_Class:
            case CONSTANT_String: case CONSTANT_MethodType:
                pool[ix]=buf.getChar(); break;
            case CONSTANT_FieldRef: case CONSTANT_MethodRef:
            case CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodRef: case CONSTANT_NameAndType:
            case CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic: case CONSTANT_Dynamic:
            case CONSTANT_Integer: case CONSTANT_Float:
                buf.position(buf.position()+4); break;
            case CONSTANT_Double: case CONSTANT_Long:
                buf.position(buf.position()+8); ix++; break;
            case CONSTANT_MethodHandle: buf.position(buf.position()+3); break;
        }
    }
    int access = buf.getChar(), thisClass = buf.getChar(), superClass = buf.getChar();
    buf.position(pool[pool[superClass]]);
    return decodeString(buf);
}
private static String decodeString(ByteBuffer buf) {
    int size=buf.getChar(), oldLimit=buf.limit();
    buf.limit(buf.position()+size);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(size+(size>>1));
    while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
        byte b=buf.get();
        if(b>0) sb.append((char)b);
        else {
            int b2 = buf.get();
            if((b&0xf0)!=0xe0)
                sb.append((char)((b&0x1F)<<6 | b2&0x3F));
            else {
                int b3 = buf.get();
                sb.append((char)((b&0x0F)<<12 | (b2&0x3F)<<6 | b3&0x3F));
            }
        }
    }
    buf.limit(oldLimit);
    return sb.toString();
}
private static final byte CONSTANT_Utf8 = 1, CONSTANT_Integer = 3,
    CONSTANT_Float = 4, CONSTANT_Long = 5, CONSTANT_Double = 6,
    CONSTANT_Class = 7, CONSTANT_String = 8, CONSTANT_FieldRef = 9,
    CONSTANT_MethodRef = 10, CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodRef = 11,
    CONSTANT_NameAndType = 12, CONSTANT_MethodHandle = 15,
    CONSTANT_MethodType = 16, CONSTANT_Dynamic = 17, CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic = 18,
    CONSTANT_Module = 19, CONSTANT_Package = 20;
```

See also [§4. The `class` File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-4.html).